# After install json i am install rails through command prompt i have an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i do this command
    gem install rails --version --no-ri no-rdoc
, i got error..

> ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError) Illformed requirement
>   ["\x165.0.0.1"]

Please help

Comment: can you do bundle?

Comment: add more details please

Comment: Installing ROR on windowns 7 after installing ruby ,divkit and json through command  prompt.using commad of install rails that is :gem install rails --version --no-ri no-rdoc  i have an error that shows

Answer (score 0):

You just check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-installation.htm)

You do only  `gem install rails`

After complete installation,you can check `rails -v`

May be updated version installed,i.e `Rails 4.2.4`

You want perticualr rails version, you just do `install rails -v 4.2.4`